# Using scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier to cluster

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When using sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier, the classifier has methods for predicting probability and class.

Is there a way to use the same tree for clustering: for a given input vector x, simply tell which leaf x belongs to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question - leaving it here as reference for the next time someone looks for it:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.tree
clf = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X,y)
clf.tree_.apply(np.asfortranarray(X.astype(sklearn.tree._tree.DTYPE)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out you need to wait two days before you can accept your own answer :)

Comment: This definitely something we need more docs for. Btw, you might be interested in RandomTreesEmbedding: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding The forests also directly have an "apply" function.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Maybe the decision tree classifier should also have apply? And should't it be possible to "apply" without explicitly casting to tree._tree.DTYPE and "asfortanarray"?

Comment: @GuyAdini Thank you so much for the answer, but i do not understand what is the `y` in this case. Could you explain a bit more? I need to create clusters but i do not have labels(y).